# Median of three partition function for quicksort in Loudon's "Mastering Algorithms with C"

Tags: c, quicksort, partitioning

I have a question about the implementation of the partition function for quicksort in this book (section 12.6 - Implementation and Analysis of Quicksort). It doesn't seem right to me and I was thinking of submitting to the errata, but I'm just studying it and may be misunderstanding it.

In the book, a randomized median of three method is described and makes sense to me. You pick 3 random values from the array to be sorted, choose their median value (by sorting those 3 elements and picking the middle one), and pivot around that. However, in the implementation, it looks like the median of the *indices* is being taken, rather than the median of the values at those indices.

Here's a snippet with the relevant code (full code for the quicksort function is [here](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781565924536/-/blob/master/examples_unix/source/qksort.c#L76), with test code [here](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781565924536/-/blob/master/examples_unix/examples/sort/ex-1.c#L202))

```
static int partition(void *data, int esize, int i, int k, int (*compare)(const void *key1, const void *key2)
        char *a = data;                                                                              
        void *pval;                                                                                  
        void *temp;                                                                                  
        int r[3];                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
        if ((pval = malloc(esize)) == NULL) {                                                        
                return -1;                                                                           
        }                                                                                            
        if ((temp = malloc(esize)) == NULL) {                                                        
                free(pval);                                                                          
                return -1;                                                                           
        }                                                                                            
                                                                                                     
        r[0] = (rand() % (k - i + 1)) + i;                                                           
        r[1] = (rand() % (k - i + 1)) + i;                                                           
        r[2] = (rand() % (k - i + 1)) + i;                                                           
                                                                                                     
        issort(r, 3, sizeof(int), compare_int); // sorting indices instead of values..???    
        memcpy(pval, &a[r[1] * esize], esize);
```

Note that a `compare_int` function is used here to sort the 3 indices, rather than the `compare` function which is used for comparing the array values (which could be strings or anything) to the pivot value. My understanding was that the aim would be to get the median of the values, and not the indices, in order to find a partition value that partitions the array as evenly as possible to get nlogn performance.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like an over-complicated way of choosing a random element as the pivot.

Comment: The book's implementation of quicksort is wrong on more than one level.

Comment: How much difference does it make if you choose the median index vs the median value?  It would be interesting to compare results.  But choosing from three random elements vs choosing just one seems … redundant?  I note that using `rand()` means that calling this function may mean that other code does not get reproducible random sequences.  It's better if the code uses a PRNG such as POSIX [`nrand48()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nrand48.html) with a private seed so that it is neither affected by other random sequences nor does it affect them.

Comment: Okay thanks - so it's not just me! I'll submit to the errata and if there's any response I'll update.

Yeah, the median of three random indices doesn't make a whole lot of sense, it's probably not much different to just picking a single random index. I feel like the median of three random values would always get you closer to a balanced partition than a single random value, will check with some benchmarks if I get a chance.

For my purposes i.e. just learning, rand() is fine but thanks for the heads up on nrand48